# SharePoint Calendar custom url

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I'm new to SharePoint. I am using SharePoint 2016 and currently developing a web app for teamsite.I have a SharePoint calendar. When i click on "add" to create an event, it open up a form in a dialog mode. How do i change it such that when i click, it will open in new window instead of dialog mode ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `List Settings of that calendar list-->Advance settings-->set "Launch forms in a dialog?" to No and save!`

Comment: Yes did that. Currently i have created my own form and its overwriting the Calendar Newform and it still opens in dialog

Comment: that means you have written some code that opens the form in popup! just check your javascript

Comment: I haven't write any javascript to modify how to it's gonna be open. The only code i written is an event receiver to add custom form on a custom aspx